# What burns my nose?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have a buddy that, lately, has amused himself by blasting a lit JetBoil (camping stove with isobutane/propane mix) with a can of Dust-Off compressed air, to create a giant sheet of flame.

The fumes that result from this fun (indoors, I might add) smell quite terrible, hang around for a while, and burn my nose and eyes like ammonia. What gas might this be? I suppose it could be related the bittering agent. I was hoping to list the can's chemicals here for you all, but alas, none were written on the can.

Oh, and how many months of life are shaved off with every blast?

Comment: Some "dust off" products contain fluorinated hydrocarbons not just air. God knows what horrors they produce interacting with flames.

Comment: @matt_black Interesting. It makes sense, as pressurized air or nitrogen would have too low capacity. It is known that thermal desintegration of PRFE create harmful gases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside of initial hydrocarbons that are not particularly irritant, there would be a wild mix of partially oxidized staff, including but not limited to radicals, aldehydes, ketones, alkohols....

Bittering agent is not volatile, so no sense to add it. Also, liquid propane/isobutane with boiling points below water freezing point are not supposed to be drunk.

As @matt_black noted, dust off canisters may contain fluorocarbons instead of pressurized gas ( the high effective volume capacity ). Product of thermal decomposition can form harmful gases, including hydrogen fluoride.

It is possible there is formed acrylaldehyde ( aka acrolein ) $\ce{CH2=CH-CHO}$, formed from propane, which has significant tear-gas effect. Other aldehydes may behave similarly.

There is [reportedly](https://www.elgas.com.au/blog/2208-complete-incomplete-combustion-of-lpg-propane-equations/) added $\ce{CH3CH2SH}$ to LPG as safety odorant. Not sure if applies to camping gas cartridges. Various  organosulphur compounds with ugly smell can be created by incomplete combustion. A human nose is very sensitive to them.

Typical example is [thioacetone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thioacetone#Odor), which is fortunately probably not formed this way:

> Thioacetone has an intensely foul odor. Like many low molecular weight organosulfur compounds, the smell is potent and can be detected even when highly diluted. In 1889, an attempt to distill the chemical in the German city of Freiburg was followed by cases of vomiting, nausea and unconsciousness in an area with a radius of 0.75 kilometres (0.47 mi) around the laboratory due to the smell. British chemists at the Whitehall Soap Works in Leeds noted in an 1890 report that dilution seemed to make the smell worse and described the smell as "fearful". Thioacetone is considered a dangerous chemical due to its extremely foul odor and ability to render people unconscious, induce vomiting, and be detected over long distances.

You do not really expect chemists would tell you how the life gets shortened by this event, don't you?

Comment: No, the life comment was tongue-in-cheek. Your suggestion of aldehydes and their "significant tear-gas effect" makes sense, though, so thank you.